# Javascript - object literal - iteration

Tags: javascript

I am attempting to create an object containing a letter:number pair.  I plan to create functions to retrieve both the letter if given a number, and the number given the letter.  Before I can get that far I am failing on the object.

```
var letterList =  {
  A : 1,
  B : 2,
  C : 3,
  D : 4,
  E : 5,
  F : 6,
  G : 7,
  H : 8,
  I : 9,
  J : 10,
  K : 11,
  L : 12,
  M : 13,
  N : 14,
  O : 15,
  P : 16,
  Q : 17,
  R : 18,
  S : 19,
  T : 20,
  U : 21,
  V : 22,
  W : 23,
  X : 24,
  Y : 25,
  Z : 26
 };

for (x in letterList) {
  if (letterList.hasOwnProperty(x)) {
  document.write("letters = " + x + " numbers = " + letterList[x]);
  }
```

The output is nothing.
Is my object creation incorrect? Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Did you forget to close the curly brace at the end? Otherwise it should work though

Comment: You're missing a closing curly bracket at the end. Apart from that, your code seems fine: http://jsfiddle.net/9cVMN/

Comment: No need for a lookup table: `parseInt("A",36)-9;`

Comment: @epascarello: Only that characters are not iterable :-) Btw, I'd recommend `"A".charCodeAt(0)-64`

Answer (score 1):

The code should work, only it would need another closing brace (`}`) after it. Check your error console. Btw, you really should be able to omit the `hasOwnProperty` check, as your plain object will not inherit any enumerable properties from `Object.prototype`.

Apart from that, you could write the code much shorter:

```
for (var charCode = 65; charCode < 91; charCode++)
    document.write("letters = " + String.fromCharCode(charCode) +
                   " numbers = " + (charCode-64) );
```

Also notice that the for-in-enumeration does not guarantee any order for the keys.

Comment: Thanks Bergi.  I didn't even think about using charCodes!